# Bootstrap: Responsively Scale Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scaling

What I want to do is specify certain image sizes for certain screen sizes.  Are there bootstrap classes that only become active at certain screen sizes?  This would be optimal. This way I could do something like `<img class = "only-active-on-mobile" src="myimage.jpg">` right?

My code thus far is:

```
   <div class="media">
      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object img-rounded" style="" src="<%= image_path('MY_IMG_THAT_NEEDS_RESIZING.jpg') %>">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        <!-- Nested media object -->
        <div class="media">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Depending on what version of bootstrap you are using, what you are looking for is called utility classes, .hidden-mobile/.show-mobile etc for bootstrap 2, .visible-lg/.hidden-lg for bootstrap 3 for more info [refer to the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: On a side note if you want to responsively scale an image, specify a width but leave the height:auto; as that will preserve the aspect ratio

Comment: I am using 3, could you provide me an example on how I could set an image for mobile, and an image for anything greater?  The greater image should be invisible when the mobile is showing, and vice versa. @PatsyIssa

Comment: add the class .visible-xs to the image, that will make it show only on mobile have another image in it's place with the class .hidden-xs that will make it show on mobile and be hidden on the rest. Check out the link in my first comment you can find all the classes there.

Comment: @PatsyIssa Thanks that helps immensely.  If you add that to the answer I'll mark it correct.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap offers a set of "utility" classes for this exact purpose, `.visible-` and `.hidden-`.

To hide/show content based on device width you add the following:

`xs` for Extra small devices (Phones <768px)

`sm` for Small devices (Tablets ≥ 768px)

`md` for Medium devices (Desktops ≥992px)

`lg` for Large devices (Desktops ≥1200px)

All of this can be found in **[the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**

In your case add the class `.visible-xs` for the mobile image and `.hidden-xs` for the replacement one.

Comment: Images defined for other screen sizes still get loaded initially. So if you'd like to do this so save bandwith, you are getting precisely the contrary effect. Perhaps combined with lazy loading it would work.